# Can't execute any command in terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

It looks like this:

[image]

It behaves like a text editor basically. I can type any text, but can't execute a command. Rebooting doesn't help.
What can be wrong with it? What are the steps to resolve this?

Comment: "Rebooting doesn't help. " That seems odd to me so removed my answer :)

Comment: Did you modify any of your shell startup files (`~/.bashrc` etc.) recently? If you go to the Edit menu and select Preferences, then navigate to the Command tab of the active profile, is the Custom Command box checked?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: @steeldriver yes, I did modified ~/.bashrc recently. As for the Custom command box, it's not checked.

Comment: So the most likely explanation is an error in whatever you added to your `~/,bashrc` - I suggest you open it in a text editor and post the contents in your question if you are unsure

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for the clue about ``~/.bashrc``, i just replaced it with the the one from ``/etc/skel``